# undefined local variable or method `stop' for main:Object (NameError)

Tags: ruby, loops

While i was trying to make a loop for my code, suddenly it asked me for this:

> undefined local variable or method `stop' for main:Object (NameError).

How do I resolve this error?

```
loop do
  puts "Hello. I am a calculator. Please tell me your name."
  name = gets
  puts "Hi #{name}. Enter 1 to add, 2 to multiply, 3 to subtract, and 4 to divide."
  z = gets.chomp.to_i

  def addition
    puts "Please enter your first number"
    a = gets.chomp.to_i
    puts "Please enter your second number"
    b = gets.chomp.to_i
    puts a+b
  end

  def multiply
    puts "Please enter your first number"
    c = gets.chomp.to_i
    puts "Please enter your second number"
    d = gets.chomp.to_i
    puts c*d
  end

  def subtract
    puts "Please enter your first number"
    e = gets.chomp.to_i
    puts "Please enter your second number"
    f = gets.chomp.to_i
    puts e-f
  end

  def divide
    puts "Please enter your first number"
    h = gets.chomp.to_i
    puts "Please enter your second number"
    g = gets.chomp.to_i
    puts h/g
  end

  if z == 1
    puts addition
  elsif z == 2
    puts multiply
  elsif z == 3
    puts subtract
  elsif z == 4
    puts divide
  end

  puts "Would you like to calculate something else or stop?"
  choice = gets.chomp.to_s

  if choice == stop
    break
  end
end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read your question and imagine you've been asked the same thing by a co-worker. What would you want to see to help answer the question? Add that to the question. As is your question is very nebulous and needs detail if we're to give you any detailed help.

Comment: sorry the code turned out a bit weird

Comment: stop should be "stop". if you don't enclose it in quotes, the system will consider it as a variable that is why you're getting that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have this:

```
if choice == stop
```

I think you mean to use:

```
if choice == 'stop'
```